# Order the categorys after most threads

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one for `categories` and one for `threads`.
I want to show all my categories ordered by the number of threads in them. The problem is that I have no idea how to achieve this.

My cats-table:

- idCats
- name
- rules

My threads-table:

- idThreads
- title
- content
- category
- creator
- votes
- created

The category in my threads-table contains the id of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should give you a list of category names and their corresponding thread counts in descending order:

```
select
    c.name,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
from
    cats c
    left join threads t
        on  c.idCats = t.category
group by
    c.name
order by
    cnt desc
```

Comment: Does the `count(*)` work correctly there? I would have thought you'd need to count something from the `threads` table specifically. Mind you, MySQL is much more forgiving than the databases I'm used to